# PHP shared memory on windows server

Tags: php, windows, shared-memory

- I want to store small array (aprox `1Mb`) for a massive access load.
- I don't want to use database.
- I don't need to secure that data.
- I will change this array only one-time per minute, but I have thousands of access each minute for read that data.

Actually I'm using `PHP shared memory segment` **`shmop`** which works fine. But often causes a PHP exeption which results by **Apache restart**.

Do exist some way to do the same memory operations in windows by any other PHP module?

**Do exist better way to handle this data for a fast access?**

I don't care about security or reliability of that stored data.

how i work with shared memory variable (`$shm`):

```
visitor calls $shm.
if ($shm exists, and is not older than 1 minute): return $shm;
else: create new $shm, return $shm;

visitor2  calls $shm.
if ($shm exists, and is not older than 1 minute): return $shm;
else: create new $shm, return $shm;
```

etc ...

Apache 2.4.23 (Win64) PHP 5.5.3

Comment: Yes these does exist a PHP method a few in fact. What version of PHP are you using

Comment: cool! Apache/2.4.23 (Win64) PHP/5.5.3

Comment: Do a google search for `php cache` and take your pick

Comment: @RiggsFolly if i understand, caching like APC will affect all server environment. Or im wrong? Do you mean different caching?

Comment: Problem here is, we cannot know all the in's and out's of your server config. So only you can make a decision as to what will work for you

Comment: Im finding some PHP native solution, like a function or another PHP module running on windows machine

Comment: You can try `APCu` https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.apcu.php

Comment: @piotrekkr form the doc:Both APC and APCu share the memory across the same process they run in however you cannot use that with different processes. That means i cannot save data in one user window and read the same data with another connected user?

Comment: It depends on how you serving your app. Look here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34533695/is-the-new-apcu-apc-user-cache-shared-between-processes

Comment: It exactly means, if i invoke APCu variable storage from one computer visiting my server, i can read it from another computer visiting server?

Comment: If you are using `apache` with `php-fpm` every request should span new subprocess of `php-fpm master process` and will have access to shared memory of parent process. You can read cache on one computer and write to same cache on another. It should work event when apache restarts since apache and `php-fpm` are different processes. But If you are using `mod_php` it won't work after `apache` restart because shared memory is managed by apache process and is wiped out after restart. You could also use `memcached` or `redis` but you have to install it on your server as it is not part of PHP.