# APCu: accessing common cache from WebServer & CLI

Tags: php, caching, apc

I have a webapp (running under Apache) which populates some values in an APCu cache.

I'm trying to access this APCu cache from command line (yes, I've enabled (and tested) the cache for CLI processes in the INI file) but I don't seem to be able to retrieve anything from the cache.

As such, my fundamental question is: is it possible to share a cache between an Apache instance and a CLI process? Any special tips/tricks that I should be aware of in order to get this to work?

Comment: The answer is unfortunately no. APCu for the web server and the CLI environments are isolated from each other. I had the same issue recently and had to go with another caching strategy, since I wanted to update the cache from both CLI and the Web server.

Comment: Thank you for confirming/clarifying. I'll switch to a different caching engine.

Comment: It's sad to hear this, let me try others.

Comment: The Q seems quite close to this one, well answered: [Is the new APCu APC User Cache shared between processes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34533695/is-the-new-apcu-apc-user-cache-shared-between-processes)