# "shmop_open(): unable to attach or create shared memory segment 'No error':"?

Tags: windows-10, php

I get this every time I try to create an account to ask this on Stack Overflow:

> Oops! Something Bad Happened!
>
> We apologize for any inconvenience, but an unexpected error occurred while you were browsing our site.
>
> It’s not you, it’s us. This is our fault.

That's the reason I post it here. I literally cannot ask it on Overflow, even after spending hours of my day (on and off) repeating my attempts and solving a million reCAPTCHA puzzles. Can you maybe fix this error soon?

---

With no meaningful/complete examples, and basically no documentation whatsoever, I've been trying to use the "shmop" part of PHP for many years. Now I *must* find a way to send data between two different CLI PHP scripts running on the same machine, without abusing the database for this. It must work without database support, which means I'm trying to use shmop, but it doesn't work at all:

```
$shmopid = shmop_open(1, 'w', 0644, 99999); // I have no idea what the "key" is supposed to be. It says: "System's id for the shared memory block. Can be passed as a decimal or hex.", so I've given it a 1 and also tried with 123. It gave an error when I set the size to 64, so I increased it to 99999. That's when the error changed to the one I now face above.
shmop_write($shmopid, 'meow 123', 0); // Write "meow 123" to the shared variable.

while (1)
{
    $shared_string = shmop_read($shmopid, 0, 8); // Read the "meow 123", even though it's the same script right now (since this is an example and minimal test).
    var_dump($shared_string);
    sleep(1);
}
```

I get the error for the first line:

```
shmop_open(): unable to attach or create shared memory segment 'No error':
```

What does that mean? What am I doing wrong? Why is the manual so insanely cryptic for this? Why isn't this just a built-in "superarray" that can be accessed across the scripts?

Comment: Whilst I'm sympathetic to your SO issue, the question isn't on-topic here. I'd try the Contact link in SO & see if you can get your original issue fixed.

Answer (score 0):

### About CLI:

It cannot work in standalone CLI processes, as an answer here says:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34533749

The master process is the one to hold the shared memory block, so you will have to use `php-fpm` or `mod_php` or some other web/service-running version, and maybe even start/request/stop it all from a CLI php script.

### About shmop usage itself:

Use "c" mode in `shmop_open()` for creating the segment before it can be used with "a" or "w".

I stumbled on this error in a different scenario where shared memory is completely optional to speed up some repeated operations. So I wanted to try reading first without knowing memory size and then allocate from actual data when needed. In my case I had to call it as `@shmop_open()` to hide this error output.

### About shmop on Windows:

PHP 7 crashed Apache worker process causing its restart with status 3221225477 when trying to reallocate a segment with the same predefined (arbitrary number) key but different size, even after `shmop_delete()`. As a workaround for this, I took `filemtime()` of the source file which contains data to be stored in memory, and used that timestamp as the key in `shmop_open()`. It still was not flawless IIRC, and I don't know if it would cause memory leaks, but it was enough to test my code which would mainly run on Linux anyway.

Finally, as of PHP version 8.0.7, shmop seems to work fine with Apache 2.4.46 and `mod_php` in Windows 10.